# How to politely reply to adviser for his mistake

Tags: phd, research-process, advisor, abstract

I sent one abstract to my supervisor, which he approved and said it is fine. Later on, when the same abstract was published and circulated on university email, he sent me an email and stating that this Abstract is not good and you should have checked it with me before sending for circulation. I have his email of approval and I know he also does know that I checked this abstract with him before submission but seems he want me to take the blame. How do I cope with this situation, I don't want the relation turning bad or aggressive for both of us.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest a slightly longer response than [Nicole's answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/77225/14017) that allows for a somewhat graceful exit and has less potential for coming across as reproachful between the lines:

> I am not sure which part you are referring to; you did approve the abstract as such (see attached), but were you maybe referring to another piece of text?

Comment: Yes exactly, actually i gone through email again, i sent him only abstract no other text attached with the email. And he replied with "Thats fine," followed by some other direction on other work. any how i replied to him and apologised for the confusion if any and cleared my self, lets hope he understand

Answer (score 2):

It's possible he's simply forgotten.  Simpler is better in your response.  Reply to his email as follows and attach his earlier email:

> You did approve it.  See attached.